# Inconsistent occurrence of [Errno 13] Permission denied when writing to file

Tags: python, permissions, redhat

I have some python code writing into a file at certain intervals with

```
chainer.serializers.save_npz(model_path, model)
```

where `model` is a [Chainer](https://chainer.org/) model and `model_path` is set to an existing, writable path, `models/my_test.model`.

At random points during execution of the code, after numerous successful writes promtps:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

I am running the code through ssh on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo) system. There is plenty of free space so that's not the problem.

I tried changing the permissions of the file with chmod before every write, but it didn't change anything.

One other odd thing I noticed is that even though I'm running the python code with a shell script that should run a few programs in turn, if one breaks because of the permission error, the next one doesn't start up.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Could you post some of your code so we can see what might be happening

Comment: Make sure that the previous execution is completed before triggering the new run. If the previous instance of the program is still running ,then it might create this issue

Comment: @PARMESH, the problem occurs within the execution of a single python script. I am not sure how I can check if the previous writing into the file is complete, but there is at least a minute between each write.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with the server where I was running the job: it is a remote server, which issues a 10-hour ticket when I ssh into it, and once the ticket expires it kills all jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when the previous run that was triggered is still doing the task on the file. So make sure there is no handle open on the file using below code snippet. If is open then close the handle or wait for it to complete

```
import psutil

def has_handle(fpath):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            for item in proc.open_files():
                if fpath == item.path:
                    return True
        except Exception:
            pass

    return False
```

Comment: I tried that (if has_handle() returns True, I don't write into the file) but the problem persists.